# How to retrieve the drawable name using id?

Tags: android

I have an ImageView that changes depending on what Imagebutton was clicked so I was trying to get the name of the ImageButton that was pressed and since all that I know is the id of the ImageView, I was wondering how to retrieve the name of the drawable. I searched over the internet and all I found was ways of getting the id using drawable name or getting the entire file path of the drawable, so is there a way to get the name of the drawable and without the extension also, Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by "name" , is it drawable id ??

Comment: the file name in the drawable folder, for example "imagename.png" how to get the "imagename" part @DavidJhons

Comment: The imagename would actually be `R.drawable.imagename` which is an `int`.

Comment: @DeeV , ok then how do I take the imagename form the "R.drawable.imagename" and make it a string?

Answer (score 1):

Since an ImageButton is an ImageView you could use tagging:

```
ImageButton button = (ImageButton) findViewByID(R.id.buttonId)// your button
button.setTag("youDrawableName"); // your drawable name
```

And read it as you need it:

```
String drawableName = (String) button.getTag();
```

Comment: I don't know the name of the drawable, it changes depending on what the user pressed in the previous activity and it can't be a constant name.

Comment: Do you have the id of the drawable? You could use `getContext().getResources().getResourceName(R.drawable.your_drawable); `  and get the last part after the "/".

Comment: I have the Id of the drawable but not the name of the drawable. what I mean is that I have this id = "R.id.img" and I don't have this "R.drawable.imagename"